# What is the name of inattention/autopilot phenomenon that results in 'swapping out' errors

Tags: cognitive-psychology, attention, multi-tasking

Suppose I am doing the laundry while simultaneously taking out the trash, so am carrying a bag of dirty clothes in one hand and a bag of rubbish in the other.  I might be on autopilot where I lift up the lid of the garbage bin, throw my laundry into it and turn to walk away before then realising what I have done: thrown the wrong bag one into the bin i.e. "right idea, wrong object".

I know that it's some sort of inattention effect that is studied in cognitive psychology, but can somebody tell me what the correct name for this phenomenon is?

**edit**
Dual-task interference is closer to the concept I'm looking for

Comment: [Absent-mindedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absent-mindedness)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Stroop Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect#Automaticity) is more for rapid-fire tasks and task switching.

[Unconscious Thought Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_thought_theory#The_deliberation-without-attention_effect) may be related.

Absent-mindedness can lead to automatic behaviors or [automatisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatisms).

Highway hypnosis is similar, where you don't remember the task you've done even though it's correct.

Otherwise, making a mistake due to habit/habituation?